# google drive connect service in C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I create an application in vb.net which i use google drive api . Now , i want to convert it in C# , i used conversion program and i found the error in connect service (this is a second time when i use c# in my applications )
Here is the code

```
   private void CreateService()
    {
        // change le mot de passe 
        dynamic ClientId = "*************";
        dynamic ClientSecret = "****************";
        // ClientId et clientSecret sont deux èléments fourni lors du generation d'un projet dans la  plateform de google
        UserCredential MyUserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
        { ClientId = ClientId, ClientSecret = ClientSecret },{ DriveService.Scope.Drive }, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;
        Service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {HttpClientInitializer = MyUserCredential});}
```

the errors in this instruction

```
{ DriveService.Scope.Drive }, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

he can't accept { }, and also result is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AuthorizeAsync` function is expecting an array definition for the `scope` parameter. I tried it with the Google Drive Nuget package `Google.Api.Drive.v1`. It didn't define the scope `DriveService.Scope.Drive`, so I changed that to `DriveService.Scope.DriveFile`. If you're using a different version of the Nuget Package you may not need to change this.

This is the code with my changes:

```
    private void CreateService()
    {
        // change le mot de passe 
        dynamic ClientId = "*************";
        dynamic ClientSecret = "****************";

        // ClientId et clientSecret sont deux èléments fourni lors du generation d'un projet dans la  plateform de google
        UserCredential MyUserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ClientSecret
            },
            new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None).Result;

        Service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = MyUserCredential
        });
    }
```